# Generating c# programatically and compiling...issues

Tags: c#

Hello all,
              We are creating a dll on the fly for security, we are attempting to have a dll generated and pushed to clients as a challenge response system... with this we are generating 20 variables each with a unique guid and then programatically selecting which one is referenced in the code... however once it compiles this it no longer has the extra dummy variables in it, just the one that it used.

Does anyone know what i can change in the compiler options to make it stop doing this or trick it into no optimizing those out?

I've tried

```
U = "71d41342-e56e-4643-b12f-24df0b4506ae";
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(U);
string V = "";
```

referencing it in debug writeline but that didnt seem to be enough to get it to keep it. i also added /Od to disablke optimizations but this didnt seem to help either! Any help would be appreciated

Comment: try putting `static const string` in front of your declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options to achieve that:

- add those variables to a `Dictionary` in a consturctor and provide a method to iterate that `Dictionary`
  OR
- try putting `static reaonly string` in front of that declarations